# Reestruccturacion de dataframe que tiene una fila unica

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Dispongo de un dataframe tal que esí:(Dos columnas)

```
ES              DATA
..............................................................
CLIENTE         JUAN
CALLE           LARGA
NUM             6
PISO            4
CLIENTE         FRAN
CALLE           ANCHA
NUM             9
PISO            3
CALLE           OTRA
NUMERO          1
PISO            8
CLIENTE         GERMAN
CALLE           BUÑUEL
NUM             1
PISO            0
CALLE           ABEDUL
NUM             9
PISO            1
CALLE           LORCA
NUM             2
PISO            5
```

El caso es que CALLE, NUM, PISO pertenecen justo al cliente anterior pero no tienen el mismo numero de indices correspondientes ya que todos no tienen la misma cantidad de calle, num, piso..
La salida que busco es algo asi..

```
CLIENTE     CALLE     NUM    PISO    CALLE    NUM    PISO    CALLE    NUM    PISO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
JUAN        LARGA      6      4      NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN      NaN
FRAN        ANCHA      9      3      OTRA      1      8       NaN     NaN     NaN
GERMAN      BUÑUEL     1      0      ABEDUL    9      1       LORCA    2    5
```

Comment: He editado tu pregunta para ponerle "marcas de código" (```) alrededor de las tablas, esperando que eso mejrase la legibilidad, pero sigue sin entenderse gran cosa por culpa de los guiones. ¿Puedes editar tú esas tablas y dejarlas de modo que se vean bien? Supongo que tus tablas reales tienen espacios en vez de guiones y que todo estará alineado verticalmente.

Comment: @abulafia editada, creo que asi mas claro...Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En general soy muy contrario a utilizar bucles explícitos cuando se trabaja con dataframes pandas, pero en este caso me temo que no hay otra forma (o a mi no se me ha ocurrido).

Si se plantea un bucle que itere por las filas, una idea podría ser la siguiente. Se trata de crear una lista de diccionarios, de modo que cada elemento de la lista será una fila del dataframe final. El diccionario a construir tendrá como claves "nombre", "calle1", "num1", "piso1", "calle2", "num2", "piso2", etc... Una vez creada esa lista convertirla a otro dataframe es trivial (basta un `pd.DataFrame(lista)`.

¿Cómo podríamos construir una lista así? La idea es la siguiente:

- Comenzar con una `lista` vacía y un diccionario `d` vacío.
- Iterar por las filas. Para cada fila:

  - Si la fila corresponde a un NOMBRE, volcar el diccionario `d` que estaba en construcción a la lista (si `d` no estaba vacío, lo que ocurriría en la primera fila)
  - Además inicializar un nuevo diccionario `d` con la clave "NOMBRE" y el valor que acabamos de leer.
  - Si no corresponde a un NOMBRE, sacar cómo se llama el campo ("CALLE", "NUM", o "PISO") y añadirlo al diccionario con el nombre "CALLE1", o "NUM1" o "PISO1", según corresponda (aquí hay que tomar ciertas precauciones para verificar si ese campo ya estaba en el diccionario, y en ese caso renombrarlo como "CALLE2", "CALLE3", etc.
- Al terminar de iterar, añadir a la lista el diccionario `d` que estaba en construcción y que aún no había sido añadido (pues se añaden solo al encontrar una fila que corresponde a un "NOMBRE")

En código:

```py
lista = []
d = {}
for index, fila in df.iterrows():
  if fila.ES == "CLIENTE":    # Un nuevo cliente
    if d:                     # Si d no está vacío se añade a la lista (cliente anterior)
      lista.append(d)
    d = {"CLIENTE": fila.DATA} # y se crea un nuevo d para el nuevo cliente
  else:                       # Añadir campo correspondiente al cliente en construcción
    campo = f"{fila.ES}1"     # El nombre del campo se toma de la fila
    c = 2
    while campo in d:         # Y se ajusta por si ese campo ya existiera
      campo = f"{fila.ES}{c}"
      c+=1
    d[campo] = fila.DATA      # El valor del campo se toma de la fila

lista.append(d)               # Añadir el último cliente
```

Al ejecutar ese código sobre tu dataframe se construye la siguiente lista de diccionarios, donde podemos comprobar que todo ha salido bien:

```
[{'CLIENTE': 'JUAN', 'CALLE1': 'LARGA', 'NUM1': '6', 'PISO1': '4'}, 
 {'CLIENTE': 'FRAN', 'CALLE1': 'ANCHA', 'NUM1': '9', 'PISO1': '3', 
      'CALLE2': 'OTRA', 'NUM2': '1', 'PISO2': '8'}, 
 {'CLIENTE': 'GERMAN', 'CALLE1': 'BUÑUEL', 'NUM1': '1', 'PISO1': '0', 
    'CALLE2': 'ABEDUL', 'NUM2': '9', 'PISO2': '1', 
    'CALLE3': 'LORCA', 'NUM3': '2', 'PISO3': '5'}
]
```

Ahora ya solo queda:

```
resultado = pd.DataFrame(lista)
```

y se obtiene:

[image: Resultado]

Comment: WoW increible idea!! es realmente genial...gracias por la ayuda!!

Answer (score -1):

[revisa este link ahí encuentras muchas funciones que facilitan lo que requieres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df99p.png)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Convertir un DataFrame a formato largo**
Para convertir un DataFrame de formato ancho a formato largo (columnas a filas) se utiliza el siguiente método:

- `df.melt(id_vars=id-columnas, value_vars=columnas, var_name=nombre-columnas, var_value=nombre-valores)` : Devuelve el DataFrame que resulta de convertir el DataFrame df de formato ancho a formato largo. Todas las columnas de lista columnas se reestructuran en dos nuevas columnas con nombres nombre-columnas y nombre-valores que contienen los nombres de las columnas originales y sus valores, respectivamente. Las columnas en la lista id-columnas se mantienen sin reestructurar. Si no se pasa la lista columnas entonces se reestructuran todas las columnas excepto las columnas de la lista id-columnas.

  ```
    datos = {'nombre':['María', 'Luis', 'Carmen'],'edad':[18, 22, 20], 'Matemáticas':[8.5, 7, 3.5], 'Economía':[8, 6.5, 5], 'Programación':[6.5, 4, 9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(datos)
    df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['nombre', 'edad'], var_name='asignatura', value_name='nota')
    print(df1)
  ```

|  | nombre | edad | asignatura | nota |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | María | 18 | Matemáticas | 8.5 |
| 1 | Luis | 22 | Matemáticas | 7.0 |
| 2 | Carmen | 20 | Matemáticas | 3.5 |
| 3 | María | 18 | Economía | 8.0 |
| 4 | Luis | 22 | Economía | 6.5 |
| 5 | Carmen | 20 | Economía | 5.0 |
| 6 | María | 18 | Programación | 6.5 |
| 7 | Luis | 22 | Programación | 4.0 |
| 8 | Carmen | 20 | Programación | 9.0 |

**Convertir un DataFrame a formato ancho**
**Para convertir un DataFrame de formato largo a formato ancho (filas a columnas) se utiliza el siguiente método:**

`df.pivot(index=filas, columns=columna, values=valores)` : Devuelve el DataFrame que resulta de convertir el DataFrame df de formato largo a formato ancho. Se crean tantas columnas nuevas como valores distintos haya en la columna columna. Los nombres de estas nuevas columnas son los valores de la columna columna mientras que sus valores se toman de la columna valores. Los nombres del índice del nuevo DataFrame se toman de los valores de la columna filas.

```
print(df1.pivot(index='nombre', columns='asignatura', values='nota'))
```

| asignatura | Economía | Matemáticas | Programación |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| nombre |  |  |  |
| Carmen | 5.0 | 3.5 | 9.0 |
| Luis | 6.5 | 7.0 | 4.0 |
| María | 8.0 | 8.5 | 6.5 |